# Optimal way to modify value of a numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a `numpy.ndarray` of the form

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[True, True, False], [True, False, True]])
```

In this example is a matrix of 3 columns and two rows, but `my_array` is thinking as an arbitriary 2d shape. By other hand I have a `numpy.ndarray` that represent a vector `W` with lenght equal to the number of rows of `my_array`, this vector has `float` values, for example `W = np.array([10., 1.5])`. Additionally I have a list `WT` of two-tuples with lenght equal to W, for example `WT = [(0,20.), (0,1.)]`. These tuples represents mathematical intervals `(a,b)`.

I want to modify the **column values** of `my_array`based on the following condition: Given a column, we change to `False` (or we keep `False` if the value was that) the *i-th* element of the column **if** the *i-th* element of `W` does not belong to the mathematical interval of the *i-th* two-tuple of `WT`. For example, the first column of `my_array` is `[True, True]`, so we have to analyze if `10.` belong to `(0,20)` and `1.5` belong to `(0,1)`, the resulting column should be `[True, False]`.

I have a for loop, but I think there is a smart way to do this.

**Obs**: I don´t need to change values from `False` to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I made this implementation :

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[True, True, False], [True, False, True]])

W = np.array([10.0, 1.5])

WT = np.array([[0, 20], [0, 1]])

i = (W > WT[:,0]) * (W < WT[:,1])

print("my_array before", my_array)

my_array[:, 0] = i

print("my_array after", my_array)
```

It will update the column values given your conditions.